# Passing integer to query in golang

Tags: go

I'm facing a problem in passing a string in query in `golang` here's my try:

```
Exec(`UPDATE matches SET expected_completed_at= date + interval ? second WHERE match_id in (?);`,
duration, matchIDs)
```

duration is something like `12544`, the query read as `UPDATE matches SET expected_completed_at= date + interval '12544' second WHERE match_id in (?)` i want to read it without single quotes?

Comment: What's the type of the duration variable? an integer, a string?

Comment: duration is integer

Comment: Just to clarify, your title says "Passing string" in your comment you say it's an integer. Which exactly is it? I'm asking because if it's a string then the solution is easy, if it's an integer then I don't know... maybe revealing what db driver you are using might help...

Comment: it's an integer

Comment: ok it's clear now, what db driver are you using? https://github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql perhaps?

Comment: i'm using postgresql

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182929/discussion-between-mkopriva-and-zeyad-etman).

Comment: @ZeyadEtman I suggests to update your question to make it better. By providing more and detailed informations in the question, you'll get better answer as well.

Answer (score 0):

Explicit casting within the query should work:

```
Exec(`
    UPDATE matches 
    SET 
        expected_completed_at = date + (interval $1::integer second)
    WHERE 
        match_id in ($2);
    `, duration, matchIDs)
```